# Why is pip raising unrelated warning?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am using OS X, where I am running Python 3.6 applications. I have installed some AWS components using `pip3` like awscli, boto3 etc...

Today I was trying to install `schedule` package using `pip3`. I got the message below:

```
jaes-MacBook-Pro:Sample jaeraam$ pip3 install scheduleCollecting schedule  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/df/2c/3a94d846682a4fb94966e65bca19a1acb6f7dd85977f4e4cece6e677b757/
schedule-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
awscli 1.15.16 has requirement botocore==1.10.16, but you'll have botocore 1.10.28 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: schedule
Successfully installed schedule-0.5.0
jaes-MacBook-Pro:PyRadar jaeraam$
```

If you see the like 3, I am getting some weird error. I am fine with that, but why the package unrelated to the current installation is thrown in the console?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably because a *dependency* of the package you are installing has `botocore` as its dependency. So the installer checks if all dependencies and their dependencies and so on are installed and whether they are compatible, in your case a dependency (`awscli`) is not compatible with your version (1.10.28) of its dependency `botocore`.

Comment: From what shown here https://pypi.org/project/schedule/, there is no external dependencies

Comment: @jeyanthinath Indeed. The only ones I could find are in [`requirements-dev.txt`](https://github.com/dbader/schedule/blob/master/requirements-dev.txt) but as far as I can see `setup.py` doesn't link to this file. Very odd.

Comment: any idea or any speculation ? I just trying to understand more of how pip is working ?